# SQL Server BLOBs vs file links

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob, sqlfilestream

Im planning to organise picture's storage in SQL Server from public folder. I want to do it as BLOBs.
I read in the internet that if any file from source folder is accidentally removed, it can lead to database failure. Is it correct? Did someone face this problem? Should a source folder be kept with no changes at all?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to store the images as BLOBs, than there is no need for a source file. If you are going to store the actual images in your file system, then yes, you will want some folder to store the actual images and then link to them in your db.

EDIT:
Whether it's images or files. Usually BLOBs are used for images.